# Spring framework @Configurable vs @Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I seems have problem understanding these 2 annotation. I have try to read the javadocs but still cannot figure out. Can anyone help to explain with simple code about these 2 ?
Thank so much in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use `@Configuration` as a replacement to the XML based configuration for configuring spring beans. So instead of an xml file we write a class and annotate that with `@Configuration` and define the beans in it using `@Bean` annotation on the methods.

And finally you use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to register this `@Configuration` class and thus spring manages the beans defined. Small example you can find at [Spring Configuration Documentaion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html).

Quoting from the above link

> It is just another way of configuration Indicates that a class declares
> one or more @Bean methods and may be processed by the Spring container
> to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at
> runtime.

And `@Configurable` is an annotation that injects dependencies into objects that are not managed by Spring using aspectj libraries. i.e., you still use old way of instantiation with plain `new` operator to create objects but the spring will take care of injecting the dependencies into that object automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks @Madhusudana ! That's exactly the answer I am looking for. Also, I want to discover Configurable because Rod Johnson once said that's it's one of many hidden gems in Spring. But most of the time, I just see that we use Configuration as Java-based configuration.

Answer (score 0):

@Configuration is the heart of the Java-based configuration mechanism and provides an alternative to XML-based configuration.
@Configuration classes are just like regular @Components classes, except that methods annotated with @Bean are used to factory beans.

Comment: You've said nothing about `@Configurable` in comparison to `@Configuration`